# How to detect duplicate value save in method post using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property role found for type Role!

> RoleRepository

```
import com.synesisit.commonmodule.acl.model.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
    Role findByRole(String name);
}
```

> RoleService

```
@Service
public class RoleService {

    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public Role findByRole(String name){
    return roleRepository.findByRole(name);
    }
}
```

RoleController

```
    @RestController
    public class RoleController {
        @Autowired
        private RoleService roleService;
    
        @PostMapping("/role")
        public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> createRole(@RequestBody @Valid Role role) {
            Role existingRole = roleService.findByRole(role.getName());
            if (existingRole != null) {
                return new ResponseEntity(new ErrorResponse("Role Already Exists ! Please try again..", null),
                        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            Role createdRole = roleService.save(role);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new ApiResponse(true, "Role Saved Successfully", createdRole));
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method in your repository should be `findByName` instead of `findByRole` because the property on Role is `name`:

```java
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer> {
    Role findByName(String name);
}
```

Spring Data is generating automatically requests from your repository, based on the method name. So `findByRole` means Spring wants to make a request on the `role` property. As it does not exist (because its name is `name`) you have the error:

> No property role found for type Role!